# Installing OpenCL on linux without root rights

Tags: linux, opencl

I want to use OpenCL on a linux machine, where I have only users rights. I have found only .rpm file, which is not the option until I don't get root's privileges.

Can I do some other way? Can I download the source some where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On CentOS\RHEL You could use:

```
   yum install packageName --installroot=[path]
```

This should work also without root permissions.

Comment: Nope that's not right.  You still need to be root privileges

Answer (score 1):

You can install into your own home directory by setting the install path. These links may help you. And that was a nice question.

http://leenissen.dk/fann/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=606

https://serverfault.com/questions/11270/installing-software-on-linux-without-root-privileges

Comment: But again - I need the OpenCL source code for this. Don't I? Where can I find it?

Comment: If what you want is source code, you have to download it from somewhere. But if what you want is programming there is an SDK from Intel that provide support under Linux.

http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2011/05/09/conformant-intel-opencl-sdk-11-beta-announced-linux-support-available/
which can be found here.. :)